# CALayer not changing position in UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, calayer

I have a tableViewController with a dynamic UIView inside it, where it's layer position changes so that it stays underneath the status bar. I did the same to a regular View controller with a UIScrollView.

Where the "status banner" in the tableViewController does what it is suppose to, the status banner in the viewController does not.

The status bar's position is modified in a viewDidScroll method within each view controllers.

Why isn't the banner in the second view controller not moving?

Here is the code, it is the same in both view controllers:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{

    CALayer *layer = _statusBanner.layer;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (scrollOffset > 10)
    {
        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES ];
        [_statusBanner setHidden:NO];
        layer.position = CGPointMake(layer.position.x, scrollOffset + 10);

    }
    else    {
        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES ];
        [_statusBanner setHidden:YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: are you developing for iOS6 or 7?

Comment: I'm developing for iOS7

Comment: Could you have your view on top of the table view controller instead of inside it? Then it will always stay in the same place when scrolling the table.

Comment: The issue is in the viewController, not the tableViewController

Comment: We can't tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a workaround with this issue. I had decided to leave statusBanner out of the scrollView of the viewController. The banner and the scrollview are both wrapped in the primary UIView of the viewController and the banner is placed just above scrollView.

I was looking too hard at the problem to see the easiest solution.